# Linking a Service from different file

Tags: angularjs, service

I have following code:

JS:

```
   var myApp = angular.module('app',['ngDropdowns', 'dataStoreService']);

    myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.ddSelectOptions = [
      {
        text: 'Option1',
        iconCls: 'someicon'
      },
      {
        text: 'Option2',
        someprop: 'somevalue'
      },
    {
        // Any option with divider set to true will be a divider
        // in the menu and cannot be selected.
        divider: true
    },
    {
        // Example of an option with the 'href' property
        text: 'Option4',
        href: '#option4'
    }
];

    $scope.ddSelectSelected = {}; // Must be an object
   });
```

and in DataStoreService.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app');
myApp.factory('dataStoreService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var service = {

         model: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
       },

        SaveState: function () {
             sessionStorage.userService = angular.toJson(service.model);
        },

        RestoreState: function () {
            service.model = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.userService);
       }
    }

     $rootScope.$on("savestate", service.SaveState);
     $rootScope.$on("restorestate", service.RestoreState);

    return service;
   }]);
```

But, I am getting the following error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=dataStoreService - Module 'dataStoreService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

How do I resolve it? How can i link different controllers and services in different files to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.js**

```
// Declare the main module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'MyService', '$window', function($scope, MyService, $window) {

    var str = MyService.getHello();
    $window.alert(str);
}]);
```

**aService.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').
    service('MyService', function() {



        return {
          getHello: function () {
                    return 'hello';
                },

        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

    <p>An example showing how to share data between controllers using a service</p>    
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <h2>Controller 1 Says:</h2>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="aService.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

here,

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',['ngDropdowns']);
```

you don't need the `'dataStoreService'` define as a dependency here, its not a `module` its just a `service`, so if you need that `service` inside `controller` inject it into the `controller` like below,

```
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,dataStoreService) { ....
```

Answer (score 1):

inject it in the controller rather than application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',['ngDropdowns']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataStoreService', function($scope, dataStoreService) { ....
```

Comment: I have changed it to - var myApp = angular.module('app',['ngDropdowns']); and app.controller('myCtrl', ['dataStoreService',function($scope) {..} and usual service file as it is above. still same error exists. Please note I want service in a separate js file

Comment: can you create a plnkr?

Comment: I have create a simple service in which controller call a separate service to alert a hello:http://plnkr.co/edit/wi26jQpjZGdtA5RD6fau?p=preview

Comment: I could not see any separate file or service or alert in above plnkr!

Comment: are you sure? the second plnkr not the first one:http://plnkr.co/edit/wi26jQpjZGdtA5RD6fau?p=preview, i open it again and it works there

Comment: I can only see : var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{"chassis":"882932","engine":"17111324PT","Code":"H","tyre":null},
                      {"dest":"R0","Desc":"benz","Status":"660","location":null,"StatusDesc":"Dealer","DestCode":"USSSI","DestDesc":"USSSI"},
                      1389830400000];
});.. No service!

Comment: I have add the content of the plnkr into a new answer, please have a try. I don't know why you can't access the correct plnkr...